# How can I get COMObject function call attributes using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, attributes

I have a problem because I want to get the ReturnValue inside a dynamic view of my object... Inside the `Baan` type, it has a property called `ReturnValue`, and I want to get it. Is it possible?

```
Object ret = Baan.GetType().InvokeMember("ParseExecFunction",
                         BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                         null,
                         Baan,
                         Parameters
        ).ToString();
```

Comment: What is "Baan"? One of your own classes? Or something else?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Baan is an object that i created.

Comment: inside baan, i have a Dynamic View, and inside Dynamic view has a property called ReturnValue

Comment: i want to get this property to show in my Console.